# CSS3: using head tag does not float elements inside

Tags: html, css

I want to move the elements inside mi tag element 80px to the right.
How ever, it does not follow my indications in the CSS file. Why?

*I've find a solution using a `<div>` element. But i want to know, what it is not working directly with the `head` tag.

This is my `head` tag:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="website2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- Branding and navigation go here -->
    <h1>gonzales.com</h1>
    <p>analyst</p>
</head>
```

And my CSS:

```
head {
text-align: left;
padding: 20px 0px 20px 80px;
}
```

SOLUTION with `<div>`:

```
<div id="headerr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="website2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- BRanding and navigation go here -->
    <h1>gonzales.com</h1>
    <p>analyst</p>
</head>
</div>
```

CSS using div id:

```
#headerr {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 80px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to render things in the <head> of an html file?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Note that `head` tags are not the same as `header` tags.

Comment: Learning to program. This is my personal web page. Is it a bad formulated question? Why the negative marks?

Comment: It's a question based on trying to do something that is (a) forbidden by the spec and (b) doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You probably got downvoted because people don't feel you made much effort to fix this in the sense that any basic tutorial will tell you right away you can't do what you were doing.

Comment: @imtheman, indeed. I've confused the head with the header. Begginer fault. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `head` element can't contain `p` elements.

Specifically, the content model of [`head`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element) is

> One or more elements of [metadata content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#metadata-content-0), of which exactly one is
>   a [`title`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element) element and no more than one is a [`base`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element) element.

Instead, the HTML parser closes the `head` and places the `p` element inside the `body`.

Therefore, `p` is not affected by styles set to `head`.

Comment: NB: The end tag for the head element is explicitly optional.